# ms sql ssis mapping xml for advantage database server

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

I want to use the sql server-import/export assistent to import data from an advantage databaser server to ms sql server. I can connect to the advantage databaser using the ole db driver but I have problems with the datatype mapping.
We have several nchar-fields in different tables and they are all shown as data-type "130". I can edit them manually to nchar, but as there are hundreds of fields it would be nice if it is possible to create a mapping-xml manually for this problem.

Did anyone had the same problem before and created a mapping file manually? I do not know how to name it.

Any help would be great!

Maggi

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding the table structure to the ms-sql database using a sql-script and the connect the import to that existing database. The import-assistent then will automatically find the correct field-types and the import works without problems.

Regards
Maggi